# How to pass google login credentials to clasp login from command line?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, clasp

I want to pass credentials along with clasp login command so i don't need to explicitly enter credentials and provide authorization when using clasp login.

i tried keeping google's OAuth credentials file with clientId to my root folder from where i am going to use clasp login.

i used the following command

```
clasp login --creds creds.json
```

creds.json is the file containing OAuth client data

but it still open google's login page when i run this command

Comment: When logging in a second time is it asking for authorization again? It will always show you the login page on the first run.

Comment: Actually i wanted to use clasp in Continue integration pipeline, i solved the issue using clasprc,json file

Comment: Glad to hear it was solved!

Comment: Were you able to create the `clasprc.json` dinamically? I set all of the information of this file within an env variable but as soon as it expires I will have to update manually the env variable.